# Prestashop Add new field to translations/Fields.php

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to translate **alias** field to **translations/
en/fields.php file.**

For example,

Inside **fields.php** file,

```
$_FIELDS['Address_71581233bcc121fcc409ecce9317fbde'] = 'customer ID';
```

How to translate **alias field to fields.php file**.

Comment: why do you want to do it via the .php file?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is in the tpl put {l s = 'YOUR TEXT'}, it will then be translatable in the administration and the file

Regards